# Jquery to toggle one div of same class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function demo(){
$('.box').slideToggle('fast');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON( "js/JobOpenings.json", function( data ) {
      var glrScrlImg = [];

      $.each( data.getJobOpeningsResult, function( key, val ) {
          var st = "",id,st2= "",st3="",id;
          st +="<h4>" + val.JobTitle + "</h4>";           
          st3 += "<div class='box'>" + val.JobDetails + "</div>";
          $("#newsDetails").append("<li  onclick='demo()'>" + st+val.JobSector + "<br>" + st3 + "</li>");
          $('.box').hide();
      });        
   });
});
```

I am reading data from a json file. The div with 'box' class is hidden. Currently this code is displaying all div on click of the li. What changes should I make to display only the div corresponding to the clicked li?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the control to the function and then based on your control `slideToggle` its respective `.box`

```
function demo(ctrl){
   $(ctrl).find('.box').slideToggle('fast');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON( "js/JobOpenings.json", function( data ) {
      var glrScrlImg = [];

      $.each( data.getJobOpeningsResult, function( key, val ) {
          var st = "",id,st2= "",st3="",id;
          st +="<h4>" + val.JobTitle + "</h4>";           
          st3 += "<div class='box'>" + val.JobDetails + "</div>";
          $("#newsDetails").append("<li  onclick='demo(this)'>" + st+val.JobSector + "<br>" + st3 + "</li>");
          $('.box').hide();
      });        
   });
});
```

Or add a class to `li` and attach an event handler like below instead of writing inline `onclick` as below:

```
$("#newsDetails").append("<li class="someclass"'>" + st+val.JobSector + "<br>" + st3 + "</li>");
```

and then instead of `function demo()` write this

```
$('#newsDetails').on('click','.someclass',function(){
     $(this).find('.box').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Method 1:

```
function demo(ctrl){
       $('#newsDetails').find('li.box').hide('fast'); //hide all the .box
       $(ctrl).find('.box').slideToggle('fast');
}
```

Method 2:

```
$('#newsDetails').on('click','.someclass',function(){
         $('#newsDetails').find('li.box').hide('fast'); //hide all the .box 
         $(this).find('.box').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Method 1:

```
function demo(ctrl){
       $('#newsDetails').find('li.box').not($(ctrl).find('.box')).hide('fast'); //hide all the .box
       $(ctrl).find('.box').slideToggle('fast');
}
```

Method 2:

```
$('#newsDetails').on('click','.someclass',function(){
         $('#newsDetails').find('li.box').not($(ctrl).find('.box')).hide('fast'); //hide all the .box except this
      $(this).find('.box').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Comment: When a new li is clicked, how do I hide the previous opened div?

Comment: On clicking a new li the previously opened div closes but if I click on the same div it keeps on opening and closing. This is because both the hide and toggle will execute then

Answer (score 1):

Here what we need to do is to find the `.box` element within the clicked `li`, so we need to get a reference to the clicked element.

I would use a delegated jQuery event handler with css to initially hide the element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newsDetails').on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(this).find('.box').toggleClass('hidden');
    })

    $.getJSON("js/JobOpenings.json", function (data) {
        var glrScrlImg = [];

        $.each(data.getJobOpeningsResult, function (key, val) {
            var st = "",
                id, st2 = "",
                st3 = "",
                id;
            st += "<h4>" + val.JobTitle + "</h4>";
            st3 += "<div class='box hidden'>" + val.JobDetails + "</div>";
            $("#newsDetails").append("<li>" + st + val.JobSector + "<br>" + st3 + "</li>");
        });
    });
});
```

with css

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah; I think it's the best way to do it too !

Answer (score 0):

You should structure your html (which is missing from the question!) so that the div and li are "connected" in some way (maybe the div is child of li, or they have same class, ecc).
Right now the line

```
$('.box').slideToggle('fast');
```

is applied to **all element with class '.box' in your page**. You want to be more selective there, that's where the way you structure the html comes into play.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/owe0faLs/1/